# For loop conversion problem from python to PHP

Tags: python, php, for-loop, type-conversion

I try to convert the following Python function:

```
def Sous(dist,d):

    l = len(dist)
    L = [[]]
    for i in range(l):
        K = []
        s = sum(dist[i+1:])
        for p in L:
            q = sum(p)
            m = max(d - q - s, 0)
            M = min(dist[i], d - q)
            for j in range(m, M+1):
                K.append(p + [j])
        L = K
    return L
```

into a PHP function:

```
function sous($dist, $d){
    $l = count($dist);
    $L = [[]];
    foreach(range(0,$l) as $i){
        $K = [];
        $s = array_sum(array_slice($dist, $i+1));
        foreach($L as $p){
            $q = array_sum($p);
            $m = max($d-$q-$s, 0);
            $M = min($dist[$i], $d-$q);
            foreach(range($m, $M+1) as $j){
                $K[] = $p+$j;
            }
        }
        $L = $K;
    }
    return $L;
}
```

And when I test it:

```
var_dump(sous([3,2,2,1,1,0], 2));
```

I get the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Unsupported operand types
```

for the line

```
$K[] = $p+$j;
```

And I don't know how to solve it, do you have any ideas?

Comment: Looks like `$p` is an array, and (in PHP) you can't just add a number to array with `+`.

Comment: i think the problem is that [j] doesn't mean $j in PHP, but what does it mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's `range(n)` returns an array from `0` to `n-1` while PHP's `range($n, $m)` returns an array from `$n` to `$m`, so you have to use `range(0, $l -1)` there.

Also `K.append(p+[j])` should be converted to `$K[] = $p+[$j];` since `$j` is not an array.

The following function should work:

```
function sous($dist, $d){
    $l = count($dist);
    $L = [[]];
    foreach(range(0,$l - 1) as $i){
        $K = [];
        $s = array_sum(array_slice($dist, $i+1));
        foreach($L as $p){
            $q = array_sum($p);
            $m = max($d-$q-$s, 0);
            $M = min($dist[$i], $d-$q);
            foreach(range($m, $M+1) as $j){
                $K[] = $p+[$j];
            }
        }
        $L = $K;
    }
    return $L;
}
```